# How do I stick a graphic to a frozen header column in Apple Numbers?

Tags: numbers, performance, graphics

I want to paste a graphic on a frozen header column, and have it frozen to the header column when I scroll the rest of the table.

[image]

But when I paste the graphic over the frozen header column and scroll the table, the graphic moves as though it were attached to a non-frozen header column: it scrolls instead of remaining on the frozen header column.

[image]

Is there a way to do this?

[Here is the file,](https://www.icloud.com/numbers/059l9-MGbGnzp9ThPE8FgqMqA#IR_Filters) if you want to play with it.

Comment: In searching around the web, I came upon what I thought might be a clumsy, yet workable solution: create a two-column second table (with the second, non-deletable column set to minimum width) with the same header contents and graphic, and overlay the first. Alas, scrolling the original table makes the second table scroll away, even though it's column header is frozen.